# My search result webpart is not displaying sites correctly with query

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, content-search-web-part

I have a Search result webpart on a site and its behavior is not working correctly.

Here is the Query:

`contentclass:STS_Web AND Path:"https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects" AND NOT Title:"Project Template" -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople`

Basicly what I want to do is to display all subsites that they have permission to see at sitecollection https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects for current user.

It seems like the Query is ignoring some of the subsites.

For example I added myself as owner on 3 subsites, only 2 sites are displayed in the search result webpart which is weird. If I put myself as sitecollection administrator on https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects the search result webpart displays 15 subsites out of 18. There is only one subsite that is getting ignored and it is doing it which is correct.

What may be wrong? Is the Query wrong for achieving what I am looking for?

FYI I have also tried to use following query

`contentclass:STS_Web AND Path:"https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects`

Its still ignoring some of the subsites. Could it be a indexing problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding TrimDuplicates:False option to the query?

Comment: @Aveenav Settings -> Remove duplicates -> "Don't remove duplicates" is choosen. If thats what you mean

Comment: Have you tried removing bits of your query to determine the cause. Start by simplifying it to 'contentclass:STS_Web AND Path="https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects/*".

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Yes I have tried that, thanks for the tip tho!

Comment: Are you defining the `AND NOT Title:"Project Template"` because you want to exclude some specific site or the root site where these results are shown?

Comment: @moe Yes thats correct, there is a subsite with title "Project Template" that we want to exclude. 
But I have also tried with following query " contentclass:STS_Web AND Path:"https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects"  and its still not displaying some of the subsites

Comment: Have you tried to manually run the incremental search crawl? I get that this issue is already days old for you and the incremental crawl has probably ran multiple times while troubleshooting, but just want to be sure the issue won't be there. Sometime ago I have implemented a similar subsite-listing with CQWP and I don't remember facing any of your issues.

Comment: Did you try searching content inside the problematic susbsite. Like does this sub site appear in search results when you search with name of the subsite. This way you can find out whether it is problem with your query or that subsite is not being cralwed

Comment: also check Search & offline availability settings for that sub site and make sure that "Allow this site to appear in search results?" setting is turned on

Comment: @Unnie I have done all these checks already. I will just try to delete that subsite and create a new and see what happens.